# Join a string property which is in a List of objects using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a set of object like this:

```
class ObjectA
{
    public string NameA {get;set;}
    public List<ObjectB> ListObjectB {get;set;}
}

class ObjectB
{
    public string NameB {get;set;}
    public ObjectBDetails Details {get;set;}
}

class ObjectBDetails 
{
    public string Code {get;set;}
    public string Sector {get;set;}
}
```

I have a `List` of `ObjectA` with a few items in there.

What I like to do is get the `Sector` string of all the items and write that out as a comma separated string.

So for example, I could do something like this:

```
string tmp = "";
foreach(var objA in ListObjectA)
{
    foreach(var objB in objA.ListObjectB)
    {
        tmp += objB.ObjectDetails.Sector + ", ";
    }
}
```

This "Would" work. Only problem is that it will always end with a `,`, which is not so nice.

But I also think that there is a much nicer solution to do this with `Linq`. But I can't figure out how to do it. I tried something like this, but obviously it didn't work out:

```
var a = objA.ListObjectB.Aggregate((current, next) => current.ObjectBDetails.Sector + ", " + next.ObjectBDetails.Sector);
```

So I'm actually looking for a way to do this with `Linq`. Anyone any idea how to do this?

Comment: You can call tmp = tmp.TrimEnd(',') to remove last ','. It is also a better idea to use StringBuilder class and Append method when appending strings in loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`string.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and LINQ [`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) combination:

```
var a  = string.Join(", ", ListObjectA.SelectMany(x => x.ListObjectB)
                                      .Select(x => x.Details.Sector));
```

This for data:

```
var ListObjectA = new List<ObjectA>();
ListObjectA.Add(new ObjectA()
{
    ListObjectB = new List<ObjectB>() { 
        new ObjectB() { Details = new ObjectBDetails() { Sector = "A1" }},
        new ObjectB() { Details = new ObjectBDetails() { Sector = "A2" }},
    }
});
ListObjectA.Add(new ObjectA()
{
    ListObjectB = new List<ObjectB>() { 
        new ObjectB() { Details = new ObjectBDetails() { Sector = "B1" }}
    }
});
```

produces `"A1, A2, B1"`

Comment: Nice, this worked. And for me this seems to be the most elegant solution. Will accept when SO allows me to

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
var a = objA.ListObjectB.Aggregate((current, next) => current.Sector + ", " + next.Sector);
```